# jupyter notebook: how to set a fixed password and disable token use?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, configuration

I've been trying to set a fixed password for jupyter notebook but i always get stuck here
[image]

and it always says "invalid credentials"
here is my json file (the one with the password). i had to manually sha1 it myself because the default was argon, for some reason

```
{
  "NotebookApp": {
    "password": "sha1:b59cbb211259:e6f4c46b47130a3ad984737382893fc3d917f2de"
  }
}
```

here is what i changed in my py configurations file.

1.

```
## Allow password to be changed at login for the notebook server.
#  
#  While logging in with a token, the notebook server UI will give the
#  opportunity to the user to enter a new password at the same time that will
#  replace the token login mechanism.
#  
#  This can be set to false to prevent changing password from the UI/API.
#  Default: True
c.NotebookApp.allow_password_change = False
```

2. 

```
## Hashed password to use for web authentication.
#  
#  To generate, type in a python/IPython shell:
#  
#    from notebook.auth import passwd; passwd()
#  
#  The string should be of the form type:salt:hashed-password.
#  Default: ''
c.NotebookApp.password = u'sha1:b59cbb211259:e6f4c46b47130a3ad984737382893fc3d917f2de'
```

3. 

```
## Token used for authenticating first-time connections to the server.
#  
#  The token can be read from the file referenced by JUPYTER_TOKEN_FILE or set
#  directly with the JUPYTER_TOKEN environment variable.
#  
#  When no password is enabled, the default is to generate a new, random token.
#  
#  Setting to an empty string disables authentication altogether, which is NOT
#  RECOMMENDED.
#  Default: '<generated>'
c.NotebookApp.token = u''
```

am i doing something wrong? i am trying to access jupyter notebook straight from incognito by typing into the search bar `http://localhost:8888/tree`

Answer (score 0):

You could simply run:
`jupyter notebook password`

[More details at doc page](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/public_server.html#automatic-password-setup)

Of course you could create certificate yourself and hash your password manually but it looks like a harder way to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can set config options to disable both the password and token. On linux the config file is located in *~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.json*

The *token* and *password* are empty strings:

```
{
  "NotebookApp": {
    "nbserver_extensions": {
      "jupyter_nbextensions_configurator": true
    },
    "password": "",
    "token": ""
  }
```

This is very insecure, but it works well for me because I develop in a secure environment. Please be cautious.